# Python - String appending Issue

Tags: android, python, string, adb

I'm working on a python script which takes the output from a previous terminal window command and inputs again. Here is the code

```
 pathCmd = './adb shell pm path com.example.deliveryupdater'
 pathData = os.popen(pathCmd,"r")
 for line in pathData:
  path = line
  print line   

if line.startswith("package:"):
   apkPath = line[8:] 
   print apkPath
pullCmd = './adb pull ' + apkPath
pullData = os.popen(pullCmd,"r")
```

The output is as follows: 
    /data/app/com.example.deliveryupdater-1.apk

' does not exist/data/app/com.example.deliveryupdater-1.apk

It says the path doesn't exist. 
When I hardcoded the path as

```
 pullCmd = './adb pull /data/app/com.example.deliveryupdater-1.apk'
 pullData = os.popen(pullCmd,"r")
```

The .apk data gets pulled.

```
3886 KB/s (2565508 bytes in 0.644s)
```

Is there a way I can pass as the string as a variable? Am I doing anything wrong here?
Please help

Comment: As a side note, unless you really need to deal with older versions of Python, you should use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.popen`, which has been deprecated for many versions and isn't even documented anymore in 2.7 (although it does still exist, at least on POSIX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you what's wrong: that path, `/data/app/com.example.deliveryupdater-1.apk(newline)`, does not exist. Probably there is not a filename ending with a newline in the directory. I assume you are iterating over lines from a file or something of that sort, which would explain why you have the newline. Why not just slice `[8:-1]` instead of `[8:]`, or perhaps, just `.rstrip()` on the line (this will work even if the line doesn't have a newline, as the last line in the file might not)?

```
if line.startswith("package:"):
   apkPath = line[8:].rstrip()
   print apkPath
pullCmd = './adb pull ' + apkPath
pullData = os.popen(pullCmd,"r")
```